# Chunk (Webpack - Angular 4) Service worker fails due to chunk error in offline mode

Tags: angular, webpack, service-worker

[image: Console Error]

sw-precache-config.js content are below, it contains the basic setup along with the files I am adding to my generated service-worker.js using npm run sw. All the files location are coming into the service-worker.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  navigateFallback: '/index.html',
  stripPrefix: 'public',
  root: 'public/',
  minify: true,
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'index.html',
    'public/js/customjs/**.js',
    'public/js/libraries/**.js'
  ]
};
```

Do let me know if any other detail is needed.